# Joomla 2.5 set module only on homepage

Tags: joomla2.5

Hello am developer no administrator i have problem with my website (e-shop).
I use HikaShop componetn on my site and want to show last products on home page.
In Home page i add module  and set position, and set in configuration to be visible only on HOME page. But dont work. I configure in administration where is visible where is not visible.
I try in my index manual to add

```
<div id="wraper"> 
   <jdoc:include type="message" />
    <?php
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $menu = $app->getMenu();
        if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) 
        {?>
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-10" /><?php
        } ?>

        <jdoc:include type="component" />

</div><!--END OF WRAPER -->
```

I have top menu (HOME, AboutUs, Product, Contact) and when i click on About us and other page in top menu that module is not visible work fine. But on site i have sidebar where i show product categories. And there is problem, when i click on catetogy last product module is visible there.

Example:
--> TOP Menu

> example.com -> TRUE = Module Last Product is Visible
>
> example.com/index.php/abut-us -> FALSE = Module Last
>   Product is not Visible
>
> example.com/index.php/product -> FALSE = Module Last
>   Product is not Visible
>
> example.com/index.php/contact -> FALSE = Module Last
>   Product is not Visible
>
> --> SIDEBAR
>
> example.com/category/17-fishing-road -> TRUE = Module Last
>   Product is Visible
>   in all category is visible but i configure only on homepage

And in all sidebar is visible. Any idea how to fix this and put visible only on

example.com/index.php (HOMEPAGE)

Comment: so no1 who can help me! nevermind

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(JRequest::getVar('view') == "frontpage" ) {
    //You are in!
}
else {
    //You are out!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of modules is done via the Module Manager, not the template index.php

Sp, go to the Module Manager (backend), open the module you want to assign, in the bottom left you can select which menu items you want to assign it to.

If it doesn't work using this method, then there must be something wrong with your site.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah to long time. I fix after this replay. Ty for try to help. Mod can close this.